# How do I pass context to custom ValidationAttributes on deeply nested objects in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm trying to figure out how to tie the outer context of an Action parameter to custom validation attributes. I have the following models:

```
public class DataValueValidator : ValidationAttribute
{
    /// Create messages that include Guid Id
}

public class Data
{
    [DataValueValidator]
    public string DataValue { get; set; }
}

public class Envelope
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Data Instance { get; set; }
}
```

The Web API Action looks like the following:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Save(
            [FromBody] IList<Envelope> envelopes)
{
  look at ModelState to return error messages
}
```

I want the error messages created by the `DataValueValidatorAttribute` to have the Id (Guid) from the Envelope instance.

In the various `DataValueValidatorAttribute` methods I can overload, I have access to the `Data` object which the `DataValue` property is on, but not to the `DataEnvelope` instance.

I can think of a couple options, none of which seem very good.

The first is to manually call all the Validation methods from the Controller Action. I could then take the ValidationResult returned from the Attribute and change the error message. It seems like doing this kind of defeats the purpose of using ValidationAttribute.

I was also thinking about using some type of thread local storage to store a `Dictionary<Guid, Data>` and then retrieve the dictionary in the `DataValueValidator`. I'm not fond of using this, as it's not easy to reason about in the future, or maintain.

What is the best way to pass context down into deeply nested objects during ASP.NET Core validation?